# Invalid Array from json_decode()

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP file that grabs a .txt file and decodes the JSON to push the user's e-mail and name entry to my campaign monitor database. The JSON is wonky because new entries are added with a `][` as seen in this example:

```
[{"email":"drake.scott@test.com","createdate":"2016-03-23 10:44:52","from_email":null,"from_liked_pageid":null,"source":"direct","bonus_entry_url":"\/xxxbyn\/h1lvw5","entry_url":"https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160314-1\/tu%2BcJmnsgyUxE7HM9BCqnRjnza27dGIdr%2BHymHrFmFoprsRgkhZradPrTJ5s18p6ewxYeOOKLpObd%2FWGAS%2BDRw%3D%3D","shareurl":"http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxbyn\/h1lvw5","picked":"0","actionbutton":"","custom_3_first":"drake","custom_3_last":"scott","custom_4":"4146583264","fullname":"drake scott","id":"vvvbyn"}]
[{"email":"john.roberts@test.com","createdate":"2016-03-23 10:44:52","from_email":null,"from_liked_pageid":null,"source":"direct","bonus_entry_url":"\/xxx\/h1lvw5","entry_url":"https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160314-1\/tu%2BcJmnsgyUxE7HM9BCqnRjnza27dGIdr%2BHymHrFmFoprsRgkhZradPrTJ5s18p6ewxYeOOKLpObd%2FWGAS%2BDRw%3D%3D","shareurl":"http:\/\/woobox.com\/vvvbyn\/h1lvw5","picked":"0","actionbutton":"","custom_3_first":"john","custom_3_last":"adams","custom_4":"4146585018","fullname":"john adams","id":"vvvbyn"}]
```

The problem I am having right now is uploading the entries to my database. I have managed to strip the `][` and doing a `var_dump($content);` shows a valid JSON string. However, doing `var_dump($user)` gives me `0 array(0) { }`.

The entries will not upload to my database because there is essentially nothing in my array. Can anyone give me some insight on how to proceed?

```
<?php 

require_once 'csrest_general.php';
require_once 'csrest_subscribers.php';

$auth = array(
'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx');
$wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('xxxxxxxxxx', $auth);

$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/sweeps/test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($url);    
$content = str_replace('}][{', '},{', $content);

$tmp = explode('][', $content);
foreach ($tmp as $json_part) {
$user = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']', true);
$result = $wrap->add(array(
  'EmailAddress' => $user->email,
  'Name' => $user->fullname,
  'Resubscribe' => true

 ));
}    

if($result->was_successful()) {
echo "Subscribed with code ".$result->http_status_code;

}

else {
 echo "failed";
 var_dump($result->response);
 var_dump($user); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Yep, I tried using it on line 16.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around why you're editing the the string representation of the JSON *at all*. You *do* know that lists are not divided by `][`, but *encapsulated in* `[]`, right?

Comment: It's from woobox, sending information to my callback url. their json honestly is wonky and if there is any time in-between a user entry (for example user A inputs their name/e-mail then user B inputs their name/e-mail 10 minutes later), it'll treat it as two separate strings and give me a `][` bracket inbetween. I had to do a work-around with the str_replace.

Comment: Don't do that. Ever. Use `json_decode()` on the original JSON, and then work with the resulting object/array. Modifying the text form will bring you nothing but sorrow.

Comment: I see. In this case, my particular example essentially has two JSON entries in one .txt file. Can you briefly tell me the best way to separate these entries?

Comment: By addressing the root problem of the malformed JSON at the source, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple JSON objects concatenated in the file.  The easiest way to make the JSON valid is to create an array:

```
$content = str_replace('][', ',', $content);
$users   = json_decode($content, true);
```

Then you have a multi-dimensional array with multiple users that you will need to decide what you want from it:

```
print_r($users);

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user['email'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am receiving a blank white screen. The e-mail isn't outputted on the echo, http://paste.ofcode.org/7UZCgTHgKBgd55i42RzNEN

Comment: You copied between an edit of my answer.  Try the updated code, both top and bottom. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da4e5a6cd13c76a1ad760073d16aca6f263a3607

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the issue perfectly.